# Clear PDP contexts from modem (Ericsson F3307)

Tags: gsm, modem, 3g, at-command, gprs

I have an Acer tablet PC which has the Ericsson F3307 modem built in.

I have written some software which requires the modem to dial a connection. Included in this connection is setting the PDP context.

I do this by issuing the command

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","apnname"
```

While playing with this command, I also set the context '2' which has left me with two PDP contexts defined, so when I type

```
AT+CGDCONT?
```

it returns

```
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","apnname","0.0.0.0",0,0
+CGDCONT: 2,"IP","mytest","0.0.0.0",0,0
```

I have tried issuing the command

```
AT+CGDCONT=2
```

To remove entry 2, but it just blanks it.. it doesn't remove it from this list.

```
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","apnname","0.0.0.0",0,0
+CGDCONT: 2,"IP","","0.0.0.0",0,0
```

Does anyone know if there's a way of removing these entries, or doing a HARD RESET on the modem so that it forgets these settings ?

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: Incidentally, if I run this command on my old LG phone's modem, it removes the line completely if I type AT+CGDCONT=2. Why can't companies standardise on a simple set of instructions (rhetorical question)